# Remove UI monad with ThreepennyGUI

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

I'm really new to using the threepenny gui and I want to do something like this:

```
on UI.click button $ const $ do
        element reverseArea # set UI.text (reverse (get value area))
```

So when i click a certain button on the page i get the text from a textarea, reverse it and display it in a different text area.
However when i try run this, I get the error :

```
 Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘UI String’
```

So I wanted to know how could I remove the UI monad so I can manipulate the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with threepenny-ui, but I guess you need something like this:

```
on UI.click button $ const $ do
    s <- get value area
    element reverseArea # set UI.text (reverse s)
```

The rough idea is: when you have a value of type `UI String` you can use `x <- value` inside a `do` to get the string (without `UI`) and bind it to variable `x`. You can only do this if the rest of the `do` clock at the end returns value of a type `UI T` for some type `T`.

So, use `<-` as needed to get the pure values.

By the way, this is not specific to `UI`: every monad follows this principle. You will find plenty of monad tutorials around the net.

Comment: Thank alot, I was trying to use something like `x <- liftIO (get value area)` and I thought there would be a function that would similar to liftIO but for UI but I didnt think to just try it like that.